# Why is the blocks configuration screen is showing regions from the .info file of the admin theme, not the default theme

Tags: 6, theming, blocks

I have a Drupal 6 site with a default custom theme called c2. I also have Rubik/Tao installed, and have Rubik set as the admin theme.

When I access admin/build/block page, the regions listed are for the admin theme, not the regions from the c2 theme. When I'm on this page the first theme/tab listed is c2, and it's active. When I set the admin theme to c2, the missing regions show on admin/build/block.

How do I get the block confirmation page to show the regions for the current theme it is claiming to be showing?

Comment: clear your cache